# How to set the default filter of network in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When debug a web site, the Network pane of Chrome Developer Tools contains networks of Chrome extensions, I want to filter the networks of extensions, but  I must input `-scheme:chrome-extension` everytime. Is there a way to configure the Network filter chrome-extension default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't looks there is any other way. I did a little investigating to see if I was able to create a Chrome Extension to automate this, but the [chrome.devtools.panels API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels) doesn't provide access to the Network panel, only the Elements and Sources panels, and even those only have access in a limited way.

Your best bet currently is to run Chrome in another Profile or in Incognito mode.

Comment: The main target of Incognito mode is privacy, if used for the problem I meet which maybe a little trick, so I register a single google account and create a new user profile in chrome , I made this account only for develop purpose,  I think this is the best way now~